# Gravitational effect at different depths in the earth

Tags: gravity

Hypothetically, if we could dig to the middle of the earth, how would gravity affect the people and equipment at different depths in the planet? It seems that at the centre, there would be equal forces pulling in every direction causing an object to "float". But how about at other places? I know that this question seems like a duplicate of [enter link description here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137206/an-alternate-approach-to-find-variation-of-gravitational-acceleration-with-respe) but I am asking for the effects, not the math of calculating such forces.